# How to filter Amazon EBS snapshots by image (AMI) ID?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

I would like to get all Amazon EBS snapshots that are associated with a certain AMI (image).

Is that possible?

I can filter by tag ie.

```
previous_snapshots = ec2.describe_snapshots(Filters=[{'Name': 'tag:SnapAndDelete', 'Values': ['True']}])['Snapshots']
  for snapshot in previous_snapshots:
    print('Deleting snapshot {}'.format(snapshot['SnapshotId']))
    ec2.delete_snapshot(SnapshotId=snapshot['SnapshotId'])
```

Is there a filter to use an `ImageId` instead?

Or could it be possible to get a list of all snapshots associated to an image id using `describe_images`? I would be happy with either of both.

ie.

```
images = ec2.describe_images(Owners=['self'])['Images']
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When calling `describe_images()`, Amazon EBS Snapshots are referenced in the `BlockDeviceMappings` section:

```json
{
    'Images': [
        {
            'CreationDate': 'string',
            'ImageId': 'string',
            'Platform': 'Windows',
            'BlockDeviceMappings': [
                {
                    'DeviceName': 'string',
                    'VirtualName': 'string',
                    'Ebs': {
                        'Iops': 123,
                        'SnapshotId': 'string',   <--- This is the Amazon EBS Snapshot
                        'VolumeSize': 123,
                        'VolumeType': 'standard'|'io1'|'io2'|'gp2'|'sc1'|'st1'|'gp3'
                        ...
```

Therefore, if you wish to retrieve all Amazon EBS Snapshots for a given AMI you can use code like this:

```py
import boto3

ec2_client = boto3.client('ec2')

response = ec2_client.describe_images(ImageIds = ['ami-1234'])

first_ami = response['Images'][0]

snapshots = [device['Ebs']['SnapshotId'] for device in first_ami['BlockDeviceMappings'] if 'Ebs' in device]

for snapshot in snapshots:
    print(snapshot)
```

Comment: Exactly what I need! Sometimes there is no `Ebs` key and I get:

`[ERROR] KeyError: 'Ebs'` though so a check should be needed in that loop I guess.

Thank you!

Comment: Oh! I have updated the code to handle that situation.